# How to crawl PDF documents using Nutch 1.6?

Tags: parsing, pdf, nutch

I'm using Apache-nutch 1.6,my requirement is to crawl PDF documents as .pdf file itself but I couldn't crawl pdf file as text itself.
 In my nutch-site.xml, I'm giving http.agent.name,http.robots.name,http.proxy.host alone..Is there anything should I add...
 In my plugins I have only parse-tika, Is there anything to add...If so suggest me the link...

I can crawl .html but for .pdf file no parsetext....

Error:
 parse.ParseUtil - Unable to successfully parse content http://nutch.apache.orgmailing_lists.pdf of type application/pdf
 parse.ParseSegment - Error parsing: http://nutch.apache.org/mailing_lists.pdf: failed(2,200): org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseException: Unable to successfully parse content

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge ...Check pdpage.class(path for this class: pdfbox-app-1.8.2/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPage.class) contains your pdfbox or not. it is required for your problem.

Comment: parse-tika/pdfbox-1.7.0/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPage.class...I have my pdfbox in this path but in my log.........with org.apache.nutch.parse.tika.TikaParser@123653
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage

Comment: parse.ParserFactory - The parsing plugins: [org.apache.nutch.parse.tika.TikaParser] are enabled via the plugin.includes system property, and all claim to support the content type application/pdf, but they are not mapped to it  in the parse-plugins.xml file....I think this the problem and needed to be rectified...